# Javascript find and replace string with variable values

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have an angular app, but I have one page that needs to be pre-rendered with no javascript (for printing and PDF), some of the content is loaded with the Angular variable inputs {{field(10)}}

I pre-load the content but need a way to find and replace the string so that:

`{{field(10)}}`

is changed into the value of this

`submission.inputs[10]`

So for example:

```
var string = 'This is some content: {{field[10]}}';
var submission.inputs[10] = 'replace value';
```

I want the new string to be this

```
var newString = 'This is some content: replace value';
```

This is running in Node so it has the latest version of Javascript.

I tried this:

`var newString = string.replace(/\{{(.+?)}}/g, submission.inputs[$1]);`

But I don't think my syntax is correct.

Comment: `{}` are special characters in regular expressions.  You will have to escape them to make them literals.  Same with `[]`

Comment: Your syntax is perfectly correct https://regex101.com/r/Qberbr/1. You can even remove your first `\\`

Comment: Weird, I was for sure `{}` were treated as special characters since they're used like `(){2}`

Comment: @Taplar depending on how you use special characters they are special or not. `a{2}` is different than just `{{`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current regex extracts all the text contained within `{{}}` with its capture group. But you only want the index of the replacement, which is contained within the `[]`, and not the entire string itself. So you have two options:

- Modify regex to capture only the index, so that would look like `/{{field\[(.+?)\]}}/`, where the capture group now only takes the number within the brackets.
- Leave the original regex alone, but change the replace function to extract the number from the returned match. In this case you'll have a second regex (or some other method) to extract the number from the matched string (in this case, get `"10"` out of `"field[10]"`).

Here's an example demonstrating both:

```js
var string = 'This is some content: {{field[10]}}';
var submission = {inputs: []};
submission.inputs[10] = 'replace value';

// I want the new string to be this
// var newString = 'This is some content: replace value';

var newString = string.replace(/{{field\[(.+?)\]}}/g, (match, cap1) => submission.inputs[cap1]);
console.log(newString)

// OR:

var otherNewString = string.replace(/\{{(.+?)}}/g, (match, cap1) => submission.inputs[cap1.match(/\[(.+?)\]/)[1]]);
console.log(otherNewString)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to extract the contents between `{{field[` and `]}}` as the snippet below shows. The snippet uses a callback in the replace function and passes the captured group's value to it so that an appropriate value may be returned (`submission.inputs[b]` where `b` is the number you want: `10` in this case).

```
{{[^[]+\[([^\]]+)]}}
```

- `{{` Match this literally
- `[^[]+` Match any character except `[` one or more times
- `\[` Match `[` literally
- `([^\]]+)` Capture any character except `]` one or more times into capture group 1. This is the value you want
- `]}}` Match this literally

```js
var string = 'This is some content: {{field[10]}}'
var submission = {inputs:[]}
submission.inputs[10] = 'replace value'
var newString = string.replace(/{{[^[]+\[([^\]]+)]}}/g, function(a, b) { return submission.inputs[b] })
console.log(newString)
```